# Image not displaying using imageUrl, Everything seems right.PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Here is the function in my Controller

```
 public function singleEdit($propertyId){

  $property = $this->propertyModel->getPropertyById($propertyId);
  $image = $this->propertyModel->getImageByPropertyId($propertyId);
  $data = [
    'property' => $property,
    'image' => $image
  ];
  $this->view('adminPages/singleEdit', $data);
}
```

Here is the function in my Model

```
    public function getImageByPropertyId($propertyId){
    $this->db->query('SELECT imageId, imageName, imageUrl, propertyId, imageRank FROM images WHERE                                          propertyId = :propertyId');
    $this->db->bind(':propertyId', $propertyId);
    $results = $this->db->resultSet();
    return $results;
}
```

Here is my View

```
    <?php
include APPROOT . "/views/templates/header.php"; ?>  
  <div class="container-xl">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
           <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                 <div class="carousel-inner">    
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <?php foreach ($data['image'] as $img): ?>
                    <?php echo $img->imageUrl; ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $img->imageUrl; ?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                        <h5><?php echo $img->imageName; ?></h5>
                        <p>Nul </p>
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                    <?php
endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
                </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row p-3 m-3">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="container-xl">
                    <h3>Add Images</h3>
                    <table class="table table-hover p-4">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div>
                            <?php flash('imageError'); ?>
                                <form action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/Admins/imageUpload/<?php echo $data['property']->propertyId; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input type="hidden" name="imageRank" value="mainImage" id="imgRank">
                                <input type="hidden" name="propertyId" value="<?php echo $data['property']->propertyId; ?>"> 
                                <input type="File" name="picFile">
                                <input type="submit" value="Upload" formaction="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/Admins/imageUpload/<?php echo $data['property']->propertyId; ?>" formmethod="post" formenctype="multipart/form-data">            
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>                     
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    </table>
                </div> 
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
<?php include APPROOT . "/views/templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

if I try to display image by typing src in the image tag; it works, for example

```
<img src="<?php echo URLROOT . "/images/properties/188118_1596663122.jpg"; ?>">
```

Once I try to display using the imageUrl image won't show up.
If I display the imageUrl outside the image tag, it shows up, but inside the image tag, no image is displayed.

Comment: What does your output HTML look like when this line is processed? `<img src="<?php echo $img->imageUrl; ?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="image">` Is the `src` value `188118_1596663122.jpg`, or `/images/properties/188118_1596663122.jpg`, or something else?

Comment: I found the problem in my Upload script. I have two variables `$filePath = $folderName. rand(10000, 990000). '_'. time().'.'.$ext;`  and `'imageUrl' => $imageUrlBase. rand(10000, 990000). '_'. time().'.'.$ext,`  . The first one is to upload into the right folder and the second is to save imageUrl to database.  I just realise that they were creating diff name for the images. I solved the problem by `rand(10000, 990000). '_'. time().'.'.$ext`  in a new variable.

Answer (score -1):

what you stored in imageUrl?
If you stored info with img tag then you can simply show by echo imageUrl
or check imageUrl what actually you stored complete path of image with image name followed by extension then tag will show image else provide complete path where you have saved image like img src="path/imagename.extension" will show image

Comment: They're already doing `<img src="<?php echo $img->imageUrl; ?>" ...>`, what are you suggesting that is different than this?

Comment: This is what the imageUrl looks like [http://localhost/mysite/images/properties/366312_1596718865.jpg]